# CSS: Display Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm quite new to `display: flex` and trying to figure out something which I think is relatively simple.  Simply put, I would like a single full width row with one DIV, followed by successive rows, each with two DIVs side-by-side.

Here's some sample code, which doesn't work properly:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container .full-row {
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
}

.flex-container .row {
  width: 100%
}

.flex-container .column {
  background: #dbdfe5;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="full-row">Row 1, Full Width</div>
  <div class="row>
              <div class=" column ">Row 2, Column 1</div>
              <div class="column ">Row 2, Column 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Might someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have an extra closing `div` tag

Comment: Also `<div class="row>` should be `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: flex;` to `.flex-container .row`.
https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/XWXOPLb?editors=1100 working codepen.
by default elements go one after the other vertically. `display: flex` has them go one after the other Horizontally.